# jQuery Input Box accepts only paste action

Tags: jquery

I am working on an input validation which I want to the user to only do a copy and paste action. The scene is: they copy the reference number from other page then paste to my input box. I don't want them to manually input the reference number to avoid typos.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
$(".reference_no").bind({       
    paste : function(e){
        // i want to get the data from clipboard. how?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$(".reference_no").bind({       
    paste : function(e){
        // i want to get the data from clipboard. how?
       var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: so would i know if the user manually type the data with out using copy and paste.?